# getClass().getResource() retorna nulo

Tags: java, java-11

O seguinte codigo finciona normalmente:

```
package com.lucasdaniel;

package com.lucasdaniel;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Subclass();
    }

    static class Subclass {
        public Subclass() {
            URL resource = getClass().getResource("css.css");
            System.out.println(resource);
        }
    }
}
```

Mas quando eu crio o module-info.java, o resource recebe null.

o build.gradle está assim:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

group 'com.lucasdaniel'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName = "untitled/com.lucasdaniel.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version '11.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.fxml', 'javafx.controls']
}
```

os arquivos do projeto estão assim:

[image: os arquivos do projeto estão assim]

Comment: Você está executando ele dentro de um JAR?

Comment: não estou executando em jar

Answer (score 0):

Use o getResource da classe

```java
URL resource = Subclass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("css.css");
```